Trying to setup Jupyter Notebook & Pyspark on AWS EC2
when I am trying to connect to Jupyter Notebook which is installed in my AWS EC2 instance then I am getting below error:

Can any one please help me to fix this issue. I have already tried :
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
But this is also not working. Any help would be helpful. Thanks!
